# STM32H7 + external SDRAM - memcpy with length 3 crashes - word boundaries, cache settings?

Tags: caching, gcc, stm32, memcpy

I have a project running on an STM32H753ieval board with heap in external memory, with freeRTOS, modelled on the STM32 cube demos.

At the moment the MPU and cache are not enabled. (as far as I can tell, their functions are commented out)

this works in the main() function, where a and b are in internal ram.

```
int* aptr;
int* bptr;

int main()
{
    //  MPU_Config();
    //  CPU_CACHE_Enable();

    int a[100]; int b[100];
    memcpy(a, b, 3);
    aptr = a;
    bptr = b;
    ...
```

however, when a freeRTOS thread creates variables on the heap, memcpy doesnt work with some length values.

```
static void mymemcpy(char* dst, char* src, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        dst[i] = src[i];
    }
}

void StartThread(void* arg)
{
    int a[100]; int b[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        memcpy(aptr, bptr, i);   //works, using same mem as main
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mymemcpy(a, b, i);       //works, using external ram mem, but with mymemcpy
    }
    memcpy(a, b, 4);             //works, seems not a overrun issue
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { 
        memcpy(a, b, i);         //jumps to random memory when i == 3, probably an undefined handler
    }
    while(1);
}
```

This is the first time I've dealt with a caching micro, and external ram.

Is this a cache issue, ram issue, library issue? How do i fix it?

Note: I don't care that the arrays are uninitialised. I'm happy copying garbage.

Comment: Is is the same SRAM not the external memory. You do not use any dynamic allocation here.

Comment: The dynamic allocation happens in the freeRTOS code that fires the thread.

Comment: Not for the local variables. It allocates globally and then sets the stack pointer. Use your debugger and see where your data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has given me plenty of grief too. It has nothing to do with uninitialised buffers or ECC bits.  It's caused by data alignment errors when accessing external SDRAM.  The micro read instruction can access any group of byte(s) **within** a 4 byte boundary. It can't perform a read **across** a 4 byte boundary.  Examples:

```
Load Register R0 (4-bytes) @ 0xc0000000; // good juju
Load Register R0 (2-bytes) @ 0xc0000002; // good juju
Load Register R0 (1-byte)  @ 0xc0000003; // good juju
Load Register R0 (4-bytes) @ 0xc0000004; // good juju
Load Register R0 (4-bytes) @ 0xc0000002; // bad juju
Load Register R0 (2-bytes) @ 0xc0000003; // bad juju
```

Performing a read across a 4-byte boundary causes a bus exception (mine gets caught by the hardfault handler).

Your a & b buffers are declared on the stack, so you won't know their starting address. Your mymemcpy() is safe, because it copies 1 byte at a time.  However, the newlib memcpy actually copies 4 bytes at a time.  That code will potentially try to read across a 4-byte boundary and throw an exception.  Even if the start address is on a 4-byte boundary, the end address might not be.

The same issue applies to memset, memcmp, etc. But it also happens under the hood. Example:

```
std::array<uint8_t, 10> a; 
std::array<uint8_t, 10> b; 
a = b;  // potentially bad juju because = operator calls memcpy
```

To get around this problem I've enabled the data cache and setup the MPU region.  The micro doesn't access the external SDRAM directly.  Instead the data gets loaded into the cache which doesn't have the 4-byte boundary restriction.  It seems to work ok, but it doesn't fill me with confidence.

Comment: Thanks, I've well and truly moved on, but a good answer.
Is there a way to force everything on the stack to have nice address alignments automatically?

Comment: I'd be concerned if you hadn't moved on :)  I just wanted to lodge my answer for posterity.  You can force a variable to be on a 4 byte boundary, but it is compiler dependent.  For GCC, you add __attribute__((aligned(4))) .to the variable.  I'm a bit dubious of this solution, because it's easy to skip a variable that may need it.  GCC also has a compiler flag "-mno-unaligned-access".  Note that static data in newlib will not be compiled with this flag.  The only reliable way I've found is using the cache, but I don't have any concrete evidence to prove it..

Answer (score 0):

The device likely crashes because reads to initialized memory may not have correct ECC bits set and when the processor discovers this during the read operation it faults on a double bit error.

Write to the memory first and then read it or configure your linker
to zero initialize your heap area... this may require assembly code to get the correct sequencing going to enable the ram first othewise the zero init may fail